# how does the equation one solved in equation two

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, binomial-coefficients

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{\left [ (x-b)+(b-a) \right ]^k}{k!}$$

the below equation is derived from the above equation . Could anyone you please explain how did the author solved it . I'm learning fractional calculus for my research

$$\sum_{j=0}^{k}\frac{[x-b]^j[b-a]^{k-j}}{j!(k-j)!}$$

Comment: Hint: Binomial Theorem

Comment: It's the binomial theorem in action, viz $(a+b)^n = \sum_j a^{j}b^{n-j}\binom{n}{j}$

Comment: @Bacon @ Michael Burr thank you